# JQM pagecontainer change redirects back to home page automatically

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working with a single page model
JQM version 1.4.5
platform XDK

I want to navigate from SignInPage to SignUpPage on Click as follows;

```
<!-- pageOne -- Sign In -->
<div data-role="page" id="signInPage" class="blue">
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content formContents" style="padding: 15px;">

        <img border="0" src="images/login_icon.png" class="centerimg" >
        <form id="loginform">
            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="loginusername">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="loginpassword">
            <input type="submit" value="login" data-theme="a" id="loginBtn">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- pageTwo -- Sign Up -->
<div data-role="page" id="signUpPage" class="blue">
    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px" class="formContents">
        <img border="0" src="images/login_icon.png" class="centerimg">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the corresponding JS code

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#signInPage', function(){
  $('#loginBtn').on('click',function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#signUpPage", { transition: "slideup"} ); 
      // redirectRegister();            
  });
});


function redirectRegister(){
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change', '#signUpPage', {
            "transition" : "slide"
        }); 
    return false;
}
```

As you can notice i tried both pageContainer and changePage methods and both gives me the same behaviour, goes to next page then redirect automatically to home again

I checked these solutions and non of them worked for me;

[pagecontainer solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922653/unexpected-pagecontainer-change-behavior)

[change page solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858714/pagecontainer-change-jquerymobile-phonegap)

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on exactly or how to trace what's going on while trying to change page and he auto redirection to home

Comment: `$("#loginform").on("submit", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); redirectRegister(); });` you have to prevent form from reloading same page. and remove `return false;`.

Comment: replace `pageinit` with `pagecreate`.

Comment: I made the two changes you mentioned, login page flashes and appears again doesn't even move to register page,

Is there's any other framework that i can use in combination with jquerymobile to avoid navigation issues I have been searching for two days :/

Comment: update your question with exact code used. Anyway, try using an anchor to navigate to next page just to make sure that jQM handles navigation correctly.

Comment: That's the exact code am using, Thanks sir